# Wygwam shows only PDF files but no images

Tags: wygwam, file-manager

I just downloaded the newest Wygwam 4.0.1 and installed it into a working EE 3.1.2 installation. When trying to select an image through Wygwam the file manager only shows PDF files. Anyone any clue why this is happening?

Tia, 
Tom

Answer (score -1):

Ok, a simple re-run of the EE installer did the trick